# TP link wn725n Wifi getting disconnected on Raspberry Pi B+

Tags: raspbian, wifi

I have tp link wn725n usb Wifi. After sometime it gets disconnected from wifi.
The driver i am using is 8188eu after following the tutorial at http://www.mendrugox.net/2013/08/tp-link-tl-wn725n-v2-working-on-raspberry-raspbian/.

I see the following messages in /var/log/syslog when it disconnects:

> Nov  4 02:47:34 arm6x ifplugd(wlan0)[1622]: Link beat lost.
>   Nov  4 02:47:37 mypi ifplugd(wlan0)[1622]: Link beat detected.
>   Nov  4 02:47:39 mypi ifplugd(wlan0)[1622]: Link beat lost.
>   Nov  4 02:47:42 mypi ifplugd(wlan0)[1622]: Link beat detected.
>   Nov  4 02:47:45 mypi ifplugd(wlan0)[1622]: Link beat lost.
>   Nov  4 02:47:55 mypi ifplugd(wlan0)[1622]: Executing '/etc/ifplugd/ifplugd.action wlan0 down'.
>   Nov  4 02:47:55 mypi dhclient: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.2.2
>   Nov  4 02:47:55 mypi ifplugd(wlan0)[1622]: client: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.2.2

I have checked wifi range is good. I have checked my wifi configuration and its fine too.

I suspected that wifi might be sleeping after sometime, so I looked up on web and turned off the power management by creating a file /etc/modprobe.d/8182eu.conf with following content:

```
# Disable power saving
options 8188eu rtw_power_mgnt=0
```

I rebooted my pi and checked the parameters in `/sys/module/8188eu/parameters/rtw_power_mgnt` and it showed value 0. But still the problem persists.

It just disconnects so often that I cant do anything over web using wifi on my pi which is annoying.

Please help, I am sure other people using the same wifi dongle and driver must have came across this problem.

Comment: post the contents of your `/etc/network/interfaces`

Answer (score 1):

Check this out .. this will fix the issue

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-realtek
```

Installation of the TP-link Wn725N driver is described here: [YouTube: Install and configure a wireless adapter on a Raspberry Pi](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=clly61d8sX8).

Answer (score 0):

Download and extract the script from the following link, and run it to install the driver instead. It will examine your kernel version, then download and install the appropriate TL-WN725N v2 driver.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/80256631/install-8188eu.tgz

Refer to this thread on the Raspberry Pi forum for more information about it:
http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=542583

Keep the script in a convenient place, because you will re-run it any time an update changes your kernel version.  I've used it maybe a half-a dozen times so far without problem.

Comment: Link is dead...